# fiddler ClientConnected time

Tags: fiddler

When I test some web page using fiddler, sometimes the clientconnected time in the statistics tab is several seconds earlier than the clientDoneReqest time, so it makes the over all time much longer than the actual time it takes to load the page. is this a known issue or I missed something?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue which is introduced by the fact that the latest version makes much better reuse of client sockets.

You're now seeing the time when the original client socket was opened, for a prior request. In an upcoming version of Fiddler (v.2.2.9) it will be much more clear what's going on, as a new timestamp will be introduced for the client request.

Comment: This issue should be resolved in the new 2.2.8.7 build: 
https://www.fiddler2.com/dl/FIddler2alphasetup.exe with the addition 
of the ClientBeginRequest field in the session's Timers collection.